# Dry-hopping creates CO2 pressure

Tags: alcohol-content

I'm conditioning an IPA. After 2 weeks in primary and 2 in secondary all activity had ceased.  Then I dry hopped fairly modestly - 75g or so - and 2 weeks into that the thing seems to have gone CO2 crazy.  Last night I pulled the Corny valve to equalise pressure.  Tonight the keg has enough pressure to dispense very quickly.  How can this be happening?  The gravity isn't dropping any more from a reasonable 1.012 (from ~1.050), so I don't get what's powering it.  Any ideas?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hops are creating nucleation sites for the CO2 to come out of solution in the beer.

Comment: That's the kind of thing Lt Commander Geordi La Forge says to Capt Piccard

Comment: @geotheory lol too true

Comment: The effect is vigorous and surprisingly persistent.  I didn't add any pressure and it dispensed for several days.  In fact I had to let pressure out to dispense.  Dry hops still in at this point (lazy brewer..), but it stopped when I removed them.  Remarkable.

Comment: That's because the pressure built up in the headspace of your keg.